# Why isn't $E=mv^2$ a general formula for energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

This is the usual derivation of the formula for kinetic energy:
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}E &= Fv\,\mathrm{d}t \\
\mathrm{d}p &= m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t \\
\mathrm{d}E &= mv\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t \\
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t &= m\int v \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{d}t\\
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t &= v^2 - \int\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t \\
E &= \frac{1}{2}mv^2\tag{1}
\end{align}$$
At the same time:
$$\begin{align}
E &= Fvt \\
p &= mv = mat \\
E &= \frac{mv}{t}vt \\
E &= mv^2\tag{2}
\end{align}$$ 
What is wrong with (2)? It seems to be a general formula for energy. It is the formula for Einsteins $E=mc^2$.

Comment: "It is the formula..." No, it isn't.

Comment: $E=Fvt$ is only true for constant $v$. $v=at$ is only true for constant acceleration. None of these are generally true. They are also mutually incompatible. Also, it is certainly not true that $E=mv^2$ is Einstein's dispersion relation.

Answer (score 8):

Several of the assumptions in your second derivation aren't valid. In particular, (1) $E = Fvt$ and (2) $v = at$ don't hold except for (1) constant velocity motion and (2) constant acceleration starting from rest, respectively. Those are mutually incompatible situations (unless the thing never moves at all).

Comment: this site uses the same derivation exceot that t=1   http://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/E=mcsquared/proof.html

Comment: @torgny your link is broken

Comment: @torgny That site's derivation is wrong. (And should be wiped to prevent such a misunderstanding.)

Comment: Could I start the derivation like this: $\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{d(max)}{dt}=\frac{dm}{dt}ax+\frac{da}{dt}mx+vma$  $$1=\frac{dm}{dE}ax+\frac{da}{dE}mx+\frac{dt}{dE}vma$$

by integration:

$$E=max+max+vmat$$

if a=constant

$$E=2max+mv^2$$  If v=c a=o and then $E=mc^2$?

Comment: the page from pitt.edu assumes that v is very close to c while accelerating ...